# Installing OTR microwave with 15" deep cabinets

Tags: appliances, installation, cabinets, microwave-oven

We installed IKEA cabinets that are 15" deep (15.5" with the doors) and we have a GE OTR microwave that is 16" deep. So we need to bump out the microwave in order to open it. We see GE sells a kit, which is $130 and it bumps it out 3". This seems excessive. Is there another solution to this issue?

Comment: Look at what the kit is, or does. You could probably mount some 2x4 pieces in the same pattern as the mount for the microwave, and then mount the mount to them. This would give you 1.5" more.  Add more to increase the bump.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that our micro sits about an inch below our cabinets  so this would all the wood to be showing. Which we don't want ugly 2x4s to be exposed. So our next problem would be trying to figure out how to conceal that.

Comment: How far out do you need to go to be able to use the microwave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and most cost effective solution is to use a wood frame. The frame can be painted or stained to match the cabinets or wall.  Most of the OTR microwaves I have installed have a metal track at the bottom that screws to the wall first that the microwave hangs on and two screws at the top that connects it to the upper cabinet. If this is the case you could recess the frame to better conceal the lumber.

Answer (score 1):

IKEA sells a board that has a metal bottom. It is 30" wide and specially designed for this purpose. I don't know if it will work with any Microwave, but it works with the one IKEA sells and The BOSCH. They said the advantage was it was fire resistant. Wood, not so much... I'm not sure if there is any code issue. Personally I wouldn't be concerned, using a 2x4 or 2x6 would be fine. Even several 2x6s covering the entire back of the microwave would work, if the Manufacturers Bracket requires that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.